# Adjust heigh for buttons in Viber bot

Tags: button, bots, viber, viber-api

I need to display buttons in Viber bot using [rich_media](https://developers.viber.com/docs/api/rest-bot-api/#rich-media-message--carousel-content-message) message type and Viber REST API.
When buttons are rendered the Rich Media element has a fixed height (see on screenshot).
If there is five buttons in Rich Media element some empty place appear under the last button.
[image]

My source sode for rendering buttons:

```
var reply = {
    type: "raw",
    method: "send_message",
    body: {
        receiver: $request.data.chatId,
        sender:{
            name: "John McClane",
            avatar: "http://avatar.example.com"
        },
        min_api_version: 2,
        type: "rich_media",
        rich_media: {
            Type: "rich_media",
            Buttons: [
                {
                    Rows: 1,
                    ActionBody: "Option 1",
                    ActionType: "reply",
                    Text: "Option 1"
                },
                {
                    Rows: 1,
                    ActionBody: "Option 2",
                    ActionType: "reply",
                    Text: "Option 2"
                },
                {
                    Rows: 1,
                    ActionBody: "Option 3",
                    ActionType: "reply",
                    Text: "Option 3"
                },
                ...
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

I need to adjust the height of Rich Media element so the element stretches depending on the number of buttons. Is there a way to set height or disable default height of Rich Media element?

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution by myself. There is a parameter called ButtonsGroupRows (rich_media.ButtonsGroupRows, [docs](https://developers.viber.com/docs/all/#rich-media-message--carousel-content-message) on this parameter). 7 is default value.